# AppOpsService:what's the difference between startOperation() and noteOperation()?

Tags: android

since android 4.2 google put a appops function into the Settings app ,but after a few weeks ,they close the entrance of this function, and they only close the entrance,the function code is also can be found in frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/appopsservice.java 。

But in the source code , I found there are two functions for check whether the operation can get the permission. one is startOperation() and another is noteOperation(), through reading the remark , i know that : startOperation is for a long-term permission check,and must call finishOperation after the operation is done. but the noteOperation is for a short-term.though i knew this but i also can't tell which time i should use startOperation and which time i should chose noteOperation .

Did anyone read this soucecode, and plz give me some suggesstion.
thank you in advance.

Comment: This question and its answer need to be edited and improved to useful to the community in the long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , after a few days late , I found the answer finally.
the difference between startop and noteop is :
startop is prepare for some opereation that will work for a long time ,like gps,like vibrator and so on , you can start monitor a permission use startop and end monitor that use finishop , remember , finishop must be called after you end the monitor.
noteop is just for the short term operation , for example : check whether the app has the permission to send sms or receiver sms. 
Obviously ,above is the difference between this two methods.
last but not least : ****